# How to add the "required" attribute dynamically to directive template?

Tags: angularjs, validation, angularjs-directive

I am trying to create a directive with an `input`.  This `input` optionally may need the `required` attribute.

e.g.

```
<my-input name="test" required/>
```

or

```
<my-input name="test" />
```

Now in my directive I have a template like this:

```
<input type="text" name="{{name}}" />
```

Now if I add the `required` attribute inside the template the validation works correctly.  But of course I need to add this dynamically.  So I use the following code to add the attribute.

```
if (attributes["required"] != undefined)
{
    var input = element.find("input");
    input.prop("required", true);
}
```

I have tried placing this code inside the `link` and `pre compile` and the HTML renders correctly but this doesn't work.

I am new to directives so I am obviously going about this wrong.

How should I be adding the `required` attribute?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to do this in the directive it self instead of getting the angular mechanism to work.  Basically just use the normal validation techniques.

```
if (attributes["required"] != undefined)
{
    controller.$setValidity("required", !(scope.Model.Value == null || scope.Model.Value.length === 0 || scope.Model.Value.trim() === ""));
}
```